# How to extract part of JSON file in python?

Tags: python, json

How to extract  part of JSON file in python? have been trying to extract only certain data from a JSON file using python.

`[{"id":"1", "user":"a"}`,
`{"id":"2",  "user":"b"]}`,
`{"id":"2",  "user":"c"}]`

I want only the "user" data as the output.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? You use both tags, which probably doesn't make sense in the context of this question. And please include a [mcve].

Comment: Can you double check your example? e.g `x=[{"id":"1", "user":"a"}, {"id":"2",  "user":"b"}, {"id":"2",  "user":"c"}]`

Answer (score 0):

What you have pasted is not a json. It's either a tuple, or a list of tuples.

If you have a json 'this'.

```
>>> this = {
             "id":1, 
             "user":"a"
           }
```

you can simply do

```
>>> this.get("user")
'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

Jsons should be treated as dictionaries or lists that contain nested lists or dictionaries. In order to address the items/values within it, you must give it the same treatment.

```
json = [{"id":"1", "user":"a"}, {"id":"2",  "user":"b"]}, {"id":"2",  "user":"c"}]
for i in range(len(json):
    print(json[i]['id']
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

If you wish to have these values stored somewhere you can try creating a dictionary which will `append` these values:

```
json = [{"id":"1", "user":"a"}, {"id":"2",  "user":"b"]}, {"id":"2",  "user":"c"}]
support_dict = {'id':[],'user':[]
for i in range(len(json):
    support_dict['id'].append(json[i]['id'])
    support_dict['user'].append(json[i]['user']
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(support_dict)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      id  user
1    1.0     a
2    2.0     b
3    3.0     c
```

Answer (score 0):

As for your example, you have a list `[]` of three dictionaries`{}`

```
x=[{"id":"1", "user":"a"}, {"id":"2", "user":"b"}, {"id":"2", "user":"c"}]
```

Each dictionary contains keys and values. If you want to print the value assigned to each user; you can try:

```
for item in x:
    for key,value in item.items():
        print (value)
```